# Arrays of Hash Table storing two types of references

Tags: java, arrays, hashtable, superclass

My question is about the bucket array of Hash Table(called A,for example). Since sometimes there will be collision in a hash map, it's common to use the simple chaining solution. That is to say, making each bucket pointing to a linked-list containing entries, and if collision happens, just adding the new entry with same key to the this list.

But according to the data structure book, when a bucket `A[i]` is empty, it stores `null`, and if `A[i]` stores just a single entry (key, value), we can simply have `A[i]` point directly to the entry (key, value) rather than to a list-based map holding only the one entry. Therefore I think the hash table will be holding two different kinds of objects(Entry Objects and List Objects).

I have had trouble implementing this method.I choose to declare a new abstract class(Called "super" for example) which is inherited by both List class and Entry class.And there is nothing in this new class. As a result, the hash table now hold only one type Object "super" which can point to both types of objects I need. However, I  have to use "instanceof" to know what exactly the bucket `A[i]` is pointing to so as to do operations like adding a new entry. I've heard that using instanceof too much is not appropriate. And there will be many places requiring a "cast". So should I copy the code in the class Entry and List into the "super" class so as to not using so many "cast"s ?

Comment: Both `Hashtable` and `HashMap` store single entries in their buckets. Those entries themselves can have a reference to the next entry in that bucket thus eventually forming a linked list. There is no difference between storing a single entry and a list of entries as the single entry case is just a list of size 1.

Comment: you could just use chaining, even for single entries.

Comment: Btw, I'm having trouble understanding your last paragraph. Are you reimplementing hash tables? If so, why? And could you provide some code example to make it clearer what exactly you mean?

Comment: @Thomas Thanks for your reply. I think in some sense I am indeed reimplementing the hash table == This is an exercise in the textbook so I write it myself. I thought the bucket needed to  point to a  formal List Object , which has many instance methods such as insertFront(), insertBack() etc. Now I understand that the List class used here should be almost the same as the Entry class. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong in storing a single entry as a linked list having just a single link. After all, the difference between an entry (that contains just the key and the value) and a link of a linked list that contains an entry (the contains the key, the value and a reference to the next link) is a single reference to the next link. That's what the JDK implementation of `HashMap` does for buckets having a small number of entries.

This way you don't have to worry about storing different types of objects in your table.

On the other hand, the implementation of `HashMap` in Java 8 uses two entry implementations to store the entries of a bucket - a `Node` (linked list) and a `TreeNode` (a node of a tree). If you look at the implementation, you'll see they use `e instanceof TreeNode` to check the specific type of a given node. So as you can see, even the JDK `use "instanceof" to know what exactly the bucket A[i] is pointing to`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now I have understood the problem. Have to change my code a lot now